# Get timestamp of deployed snapshot by Maven Deploy Plugin to Nexus

Tags: maven, timestamp, nexus, snapshot

How to get **timestamp** of deployed snapshot by [Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) to Nexus?

For example, I deployed an artifact with the version `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` which was deployed with the timestamp (I assume Nexus created this timestamp or at least the last "build number" part of it `-23`) `20210829.151247-23` (the format `YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS-NNN`). Can I **get that timestamp** by:

- Some Maven command/s?
- Some Nexus REST API?
- Other "programmatic" way?

So far I found only an **annoying :) workaround** - "right after" I deployed the artifact to Nexus (because "right after" there is a "high chance" that nobody else in that "short time" replaced my deployed snapshot with his/her snapshot), I ran the goal [dependency:copy](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) of Maven Dependency Plugin with the property [`outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename) to download "currently latest" snapshot from Nexus, thus "most probably" the snapshot I deployed, with the **timestamp in its filename**. The "annoying" part of that workaround solution is that I have to **download** the artifact (could have more than **100 MB**) to find out the timestamp. Isn't there just some "**peek**" Maven command/option to get this timestamp **without downloading any file**?

Comment: Why do you need to use maven-dependency-plugin:copy ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't need "specifically" to use "maven-dependency-plugin:copy" I described it as an "ugly" :) way to find out the timestamp.

Comment: I'm asking what the reason for the whole thing you are describing?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need few moments later - for example like 5 minutes later from deploying that artifact - to download that specific snapshot I deployed earlier - so I don't want to "accidentally" download some other snapshot artifact which could "replace" mine meanwhile (for example by some other people).

Comment: The only reliable way is to use the latest SNAPSHOT. Anything else would require locking of builds and deployments. The only other way would be use releases instead.

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to download that snapshot only like 5-10 minutes later after its deployment to Nexus - isnt't that "almost 100% reliable" when I would try to download my "exact snapshot" by putting "temporarily" (I wont even commit it) to my POM file "<version>1.2.3-20210829.151247-23"</version> instead of <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>? I assume that in that "short time" (5-10 minutes) that specific artifact wont be deleted from Nexus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236542/discussion-between-peter-sivak-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: The only I can imagine is to use https://github.com/khmarbaise/deployment-recorder-extension/. and extract the line you need where the exact value can be found....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As khmarbaise suggested, I used https://github.com/khmarbaise/deployment-recorder-extension/.